# Помогите сделать парсер для сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть страница https://www.binance.com/ru/trade/BTC_USDT?layout=basic и в правой части этой страницы есть список тикеров криптовалют
И нужно парсить этот тикер если перед ним горит звездочка

Comment: Почему после _Помогите сделать парсер для сайта(c)_ стоит знак вопроса, а не цена?

Answer (score 2):

Ничего там парсить не надо. Все данные передаются в json ( https://www.binance.com/gateway-api/v1/public/isolated-margin/pair/listed ). Запрашивайте и разбирайте его в цикле.